# How can i export the input from user into an excel using React Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I tried setstate but it is not working. This is my code please help me to save the data accepted from textinput in an excel sheet... I donot want to display it anywhere. but save the data into an excel sheet. I tried installing xlsx but could get how to write in the code.

```
const Description = props => {
    const {title} =props.navigation.state.params;
    const [item, setItem] = useState('');
    const [brand,setBrand] = useState('');
    const [color,setColor] = useState('');
    const [date,setdate] = useState('');
    const [loc,setLoc] = useState('');
    const [addi,setAdd] = useState('');

    return <View style={styles.background}>
    <Text style={styles.text}> You are a hero! {"\n"}     
    Enter The Details of the Item {title} </Text>
    <ScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
        <View style={styles.box}>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Description</Text>


                <View style={styles.back}>
                    <AntDesign name="QQ" style={styles.icon} />
                    <Text>  </Text>
                    <TextInput value={item} 
                    onChangeText={(newTerm) => setItem(newTerm)} 
                    style={styles.input} 
                    placeholder={"Enter the Name"}
                    onEditEditing={()=>console.log('term was submitted')}
                    />
                </View>
```

> .... Similarly for other input i took the inputs ....

```
    _retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(item);
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};

            </View>
    </ScrollView>
        </View>
};
```

please help what can I do.... and yes it is expo cli